# how to set java_opts in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to set `JAVA_OPTS` in a development machine running windows 7 home edition and `tomcat 7 server`.  I am getting `permgen out of memory` error when running `spring-mvc` web applications from `eclipse`.  I want to enable `class` unloading so that memory gets freed up over the course of repeated reloading of web applications.  I also want to increase the amount of memory available.

Can someone show me explicitly how to do this, in step by step form?

Do I set a windows system environmental variable?  Do I run something from the command line?  What specifically will my commands look like in code?

Here is what I have so far (all on the same line):

```
JAVA_OPTS=XX:MaxPermSize=128MXX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabledXX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabledXms256m -Xmx512m
```

Comment: change in eclipse.ini

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In eclipse go to your launch configuration of the server (something like `Apache Tomcat > Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost`)   and add jvm arguments in the `Arguments` tab in the `VM arguments` field.

If you are using [eclipsetotale](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) tomcat plugin then go to

```
Preferences > Tomcat > JVM Settings > Append to JVM Paramaters
```

and add them one by one.

**EDIT** (run as > run on server)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I find the launch configurations? And what specifically do I put in the arguments? I am not running the plugin you specified.

Comment: @CodeMed it is not a plugin, this already comes with your Eclipse installation.

Comment: @A4L Window...Preferences does not have a tomcat submenu in my eclipse kepler. And the Window...Preferences...Server subtab dows not seem to have a way to set these parameters.  Which submenu should I choose?

Comment: @CodeMed see the pic :) ... `Preferences > Tomcat ...`  was for the case you have installed the plugin I linked. But this seems not to be your case, just forget it :D

Comment: @A4L +1 Very helpful.  Thank you.  But please note that I removed the quotes in my sample code above and added it to the end of the arguments that eclipse already had listed.

Comment: @CodeMed, for the arguments you want to pass there is no need for them, eclipse uses those quotes for paths since they may contain spaces. Generally and for any console program that can take arguments from the command line, if you have an argument which contains spaces then you have to enclose that argument inside double quotes, otherwise every part will be interpreted as a single argument! So for example if you want to pass `C:\Program Files` as parameter you don't want to end up with two arguments in your program `C:\Program` and `Files`, you have to pass it like this: `"C:\Program Files"`!